# Можно ли написать?

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов

Поздравляю женщин с международным женским днём 8марта

Answer (score 2):

**Поздравляю женщин с 8 Марта! Поздравляю женщин с праздником 8 Марта! Поздравляю женщин с Международным днем 8 Марта!**

http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/letters/74-rubric-87

Не стоит в одну фразу включать родственные слова *женщин* и *женский*.

Comment: Присоединяюсь к поздравлениям. Но *Международный день 8 Марта*?! О таком не слыхивал.

Comment: "Не стоит в одну фразу включать родственные слова женщин и женский.".... А как поздравлять учителей с Днем учителя, шахтеров с Днем шахтера и т. п.?